# "les gens pauvres", "les personnes pauvres", or "les pauvres"

Tags: choix-de-mot

"The policies of the government focus on helping the poor people in the provinces."

> La politique du gouvernement vise à aider ____ en province.

Should "les gens pauvres", "les personnes pauvres", or just "les pauvres" go into the blank? As far as I know, the difference between "gens" and "personnes" is that "gens" considers the whole group of people whereas "personnes" considers the individuals. So, since the government helps the poor people as a group, should we use "les gens pauvres"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend ***les gens pauvres***, it somewhat looks like child speak to me.

***Les pauvres gens*** is very idiomatic but might have an stronger meaning than just "poor people". It is not just the fact the people lack money but they are in poor situation. *Pauvre gens* also convey compassion.

***Les personnes pauvres*** might work but I wouldn't use it in that sentence.

***Les pauvres*** is right but might be avoided for being too direct. Here, *pauvres* means people with low financial resources.

> La politique du gouvernement vise à aider **les pauvres** en province.

The politically correct expressions that would be used in such a sentence would be:

> La politique du gouvernement vise à aider **les personnes en situation de pauvreté** résidant en province.

or

> La politique du gouvernement vise à aider **les personnes démunies/défavorisées** en province.

Note that ***en province*** is also becoming politically incorrect when it means in France excluding Paris area. Nowadays, you'll often hear instead: *dans les régions*.

Comment: "les populations démunies" could work in this senting too.

Comment: @LookingForAName Yes, that even better match the OP request for a collective (group) name but I'm not sure there is a real need to make a difference between "individuals belonging to a group" and "the group containing these individuals".